# Preventing reverse engineering of Urls used in Android app for HTTP Requests

Tags: android, security

I am designing an app that requests data from my server using a HTTP Connection.

This data depends on the selected item so I have different URLs on my server corresponding to the item chosen.

For now I have hard-coded the URLs in the app, I am new to Android so my question is :

How can i prevent reverse engineering of these URLs?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean? if you don't hardcode URLs in your program, where should you put the URL? storing location of URL in a url? what are you looking for really? If you mean preventing reverse engineering your program and preventing modification, ask it. If you mean revealing your URL could be dangerous, as far as you are using HTTP even a sniffer could find URL. Seems like "not a real question" to me

Comment: @VahidFarahmand i have rephrased the question and yes it is a "real" question, forgive me if i don't have years of experience. we are all humans.

Comment: if it's http URL, even a simple sniffer will reveal your URL, all android applications are java and it's so simple to extract strings from applications. not really an achievable mission.

Comment: no matter how you obfuscate or construct your URL in the app the moment it hits the wire it will be visible to a utility like weinre or ethereal. if the parameters or the path or the URL is something you are taking action on and need to secure then there are mechanisms for tokenizing URLs and decrypting server side but it becomes more complex the more secure you need things to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to send some sensitive data from any device (in your case android), relaying on URL being hidden will not bring any security to your application.

At first you can use SSL protocol, SSL will encrypt data between you and your server, so sniffers will not able to read any data. Altought you have to verify SSL certificate when you are sending data from android device to prevent MITM attacks.

Also for more security you can include some symmetric or asymmetric encryption algorithms to your data. You can encrypt data before sending it to server using a public key and only your server will have private key. So you can decrypt data in server using that private key. There is a lot of resources for openssl APIs in PHP.

If you can't use public-key encryption algorithm you can use a symmetric algorithm like AES. It will be also secure. But encryption key should be kept safe, for example you can implement key-exchange algorithm using a basic asymmetric encryption for transferring encryption key to client, then encrypt data using AES.

Best security could be using SSL, also encrypting data using symmetric and asymmetric encryption algorithms.

It totally depends on your implementation and your effort on securing data.